# Is this the Clojure way to web-scrape a book cover image?

Tags: clojure, web-scraping

Is there a way to write this better or more Clojure way? Especially the last part with `with-open` and the `let`. Should I put the `->` form into a separate function? Is this function to overloaded (to much stuff) or is this still ok?

```
 (defn scrape-book-cover [url image-filename]
   (let [out-stream (io/output-stream image-filename)
         image (-> url
                   (java.net.URL.)
                   (html/html-resource)
                   (html/select [:div.bookcoverXXL :> :div :> :img])
                   (first) (:attrs) (:src)
                   (->> (str "http:"))
                   (http-client/get {:as :byte-array})
                   (:body))]
     (with-open [out out-stream]
       (.write out image))))
```

Comment: You have many forms with single element you can ignore parens around them `java.net.URL. html/html-resource .... first :attrs :src` instead of  `(java.net.URL.) (html/html-resource) .... (first) (:attrs) (:src)`. Why do you add `"http:"` at the beginning of src attribute of the img element?

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the parens around single argument functions. The `"http:"` needs to be added because the url begins with `"//"` and clj-http can't deal with that (`MalformedURLException`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@abuzittingillifirca made a good point in that you can leave the parentheses off of the `->` forms that are just a single element.

`html/html-resource` is actually quite flexible; it can take a variety of different kinds of arguments, including strings, URLs, input streams, etc. Assuming the `url` argument to your function is a string, you can take out the `java.net.URL.` part and just feed `url` directly into `html/html-resource`. In fact, I would begin the `->` part like this:

```
(-> (html/html-resource url)
    ...
```

So `(html/html-resource url)` is like the "first step" in the threading macro. Less steps makes your code appear simpler and easier to read, just as long as the steps aren't overly complicated.

For the `(first) (:attrs) (:src)` part, you might consider using [get-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/get-in). This function comes in handy for navigating nested associative structures like vectors and maps -- it's perfect for something like enlive. You could re-word this part of your code as:

```
(get-in [0 :attrs :src])
```

It isn't much shorter than the original, but I think it reads better, and it "feels" shorter because you're only calling one function.

It's probably not very Clojurian to have a `->>` macro among the steps to a `->` macro. If you have a situation like this, where one of the steps to the `->` requires you to put the argument last instead of second, you can do something like `(#(str "http:" %))` -- create an anonymous function literal with the `%` wherever you want the argument to go, and then call it by putting parentheses around it.

So, here is how I would refactor your code:

```
(defn scrape-book-cover [url image-filename]
  (let [out-stream (io/output-stream image-filename)
        image (-> (html/html-resource url)
                  (html/select [:div.bookcoverXXL :> :div :> :img])
                  (get-in [0 :attrs :src])
                  (#(str "http:" %))
                  (http-client/get {:as :byte-array})
                  :body)]
    (with-open [out out-stream]
      (.write out image))))
```

EDIT: To answer your question: No, I don't think this function is overloaded. When you simplify like I did above, it doesn't seem too long or complicated.

EDIT 2: Of course, there's nothing stopping you from pulling out the `->` part and making it a separate function. It might make your code easier to read. You could call the function something like `imgurl->bytes`.

```
(defn imgurl->bytes [url]
  (-> (html/html-resource url)
      (html/select [:div.bookcoverXXL :> :div :> :img])
      (get-in [0 :attrs :src])
      (#(str "http:" %))
      (http-client/get {:as :byte-array})
      :body))

(defn scrape-book-cover [url image-filename]
  (let [out-stream (io/output-stream image-filename)
        image (imgurl->bytes url)]
    (with-open [out out-stream]
      (.write out image))))
```

Come to think of it, I like this better. If you look at a lot of Clojure code on github, you will see a lot of things broken up into simple helper functions. I suppose it is generally idiomatic in Clojure to break things up in helper functions.

EDIT 3 (5/16/14): Someone just upvoted my answer, which made me remember this code and have a quick re-visit. You could actually further refactor this version of the `scrape-book-cover` function by taking out the `let` statement:

```
(defn scrape-book-cover [url image-filename]
  (with-open [out (io/output-stream image-filename)]
    (.write out (imgurl->bytes url))))
```

Comment: I have no knowledge in Clojure what so ever, but your answer are always well-presented and in a good format! Your advises seems always good! + 1

Comment: Thanks! :) I was surprised people weren't doing more reviews of Clojure code on here, so I figured I'd make some contributions.

Comment: Thanks a *lot*! This helps me understand a lot of other things as well! One little thing I've come up with the replacement of the ugly `->>` form inside the `->` was the `as->` form: `(as-> u (str "http:" u))`. Is this more Clojure idiomatic?

Comment: I've never seen that before... is there documentation online somewhere? I think `(#(str "http:" %))` is plenty idiomatic. I've read a few books on Clojure and I remember seeing that syntax used somewhere, maybe in *The Joy of Clojure*. I always find it kind of awkward deciding which threading macro to use, because I have to stop and think, "how many of these functions would I need to pass in the argument in the second position, and how many would I need to pass it in the last position?" I usually just kind of guess and then use `(#(fn args %))` as needed.

Comment: @DaveYarwood: See here: http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/as-> But you made a good point for using an plain old lambda for that. It is much more visible whats going on.

Comment: Ah! Looks like `as->` is new as of Clojure 1.5. It looks kind of promising! From the description, it appears to work just like `->` or `->>`, except you explicitly show where the argument fits in by giving it a name. You would use it something like this: `(as-> x (html/html-resource x) (html/select x [:div.bookcoverXXL :> :div :> :img]) (get-in x [0 :attrs :src]) (str "http:" x) ...` etc. I like it! I'm glad you mentioned it, I had no idea this existed. It's kind of a nice solution for the `->` vs. `->>` problem.

Comment: Whoops, reading [the docs](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/changes.md) more, it looks like I screwed that up slightly. It would be `(as-> (html/html-resource url) x (html/select x ...` etc. The example from the docs is like yours -- using it just for a single step within a `->` macro -- but it has support for multiple forms, like the example I gave in my last comment (just flip the first `x` and `(html/html-resource url)`. It looks handy either way!